# How to pass a multidimentional array as an argument in AS2?

Tags: flash, function, multidimensional-array, actionscript-2

I created and filled a multidimentional array, and passed it to a function, like this:

```
var array = new Array();

for (i=0; i<someLength; i++) {
   array[i] = new Array();

   for (j=0; j<someOtherLength; j++); {
       array[i,j] = "someValue";
   }

   someFunction(array[i]); 
}
```

But inside the function, when I try to access the nested values, like this:

```
 function someFunction (array) {
   trace(array[1]);
   trace(array[2]);
   trace(array[n]);
 }
```

I get an undefined value, like the array I just passed is just a value. What would be the correct way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
array[i][j]
```

Not `array[i,j]`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was driving me nuts!